# TS2339: Property 'defaultProps' does not exist on type '(props: any) => DetailedReactHTMLElement<{ className: string; }, HTMLElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I try to specify default props with TypeScript for stateless, functional React components and have the following code:

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  readonly sid?: string,
}

const defaultProps: any = {
  sid: '',
}

const ModalBackdrop: React.SFC<Props> = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const { sid } = props

  return (
    <div className={`ModalBackdrop ModalBackdrop_${sid} ModalBackdrop__hide`} />
  )
}

ModalBackdrop.defaultProps = defaultProps

export default ModalBackdrop
```

While I compiled code I got the following error messages:

```
TS2339: Property 'defaultProps' does not exist on type '(props: any) => DetailedReactHTMLElement<{ className: string; }, HTMLElement>'.
```

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the following solution for setting default properties for stateless, functional React components. The key row is `const propsPrivate: Props = { ...defaultProps, ...props }`:

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  readonly sid?: string,
}

const defaultProps: any = {
  sid: '',
}

export const ModalBackdrop: React.SFC<Props> = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const propsPrivate: Props = { ...defaultProps, ...props }
  const { sid } = propsPrivate

  return (
    <div className={`ModalBackdrop ModalBackdrop_${sid} ModalBackdrop__hide`} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Works but is this really the best approach?

Comment: In short, I don't think so. If you add a better solution it would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use function notation instead of const

```js
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  sid?: string,
}

const defaultProps: any = {
  sid: '',
}

function ModalBackdrop(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const { sid } = props

  return (
    <div className={`ModalBackdrop ModalBackdrop_${sid} ModalBackdrop__hide`} />
  )
}

ModalBackdrop.defaultProps = defaultProps

export default ModalBackdrop
```

Being the only change in the line `function ModalBackdrop(props: Props): JSX.Element`.